# Manipulation of LeviCivita symbol

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix in element form as:
$$A_{ij}= \sum_{m,n=1}^3\epsilon_{jmn} B_{im} C_{jn}$$ where $B$ & $C$ are also $3\times 3$ matrices. How should I use Levi-Civita symbol in Mathematica so that the element of $A$ matrix can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use it as expected...

```
SeedRandom[42]; (* Just so the example is reproducible *)
ε=LeviCivitaTensor[3]
b=RandomInteger[100,{3,3}]
c=RandomInteger[100,{3,3}]
a=Table[Sum[ε[[j,m,n]] b[[i,m]] c[[j,n]],{m,1,3},{n,1,3}],{i,1,3},{j,1,3}]
```

> (5418 -5204   -792
>
> 279  -1404   372
>
> -1104 -8254   2644 )